# unrelated int declaration impact code significantly?

Tags: c

something quite baffling me. I am learning C by myself right now. The code is simple, use getchar() to store the input in a memory block.

What I found is **if I put a int p=0; (p is never used in the code)** the code will just work as I expected.

However, if I delete the int p=0;. the code will generate an error, when I type in the console with around 13 characters (e.g. a a a a a a a a a a a a a).

I am quite confused how does this int impact the code at all...? Thank you in advance, and here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMLINES 100 /*how many lines it can have in total */
#define BUFSIZE 5000
#define ASSIGNLEN 100

extern void copystring(char *, char *);
extern void readcontent(void);

char *lineptr[NUMLINES];
char* allocbuf(void);
static char alloc[BUFSIZ];
static char *allcp = alloc;  /*   allcp always point to next available address */

int p=0;   /* THIS IS THE TROUBLE */

char *allocbuf(void);
char *allocbuf(void)
{
    int n = ASSIGNLEN;
    if(BUFSIZ+allcp-alloc<n){
        printf("Buf full, cannot assign memory!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        allcp += ASSIGNLEN;
        return allcp-ASSIGNLEN;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    readcontent();
    int i=0;
    while(lineptr[i]!=NULL){  
        printf("%s\n",lineptr[i]);  /*if int p=0; is omitted, this line will throw EXC_BAD_ACCESS... */
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in another file:

```
#include "lineop.h"

extern char* allocbuf(void);
extern char* lineptr[];

void copystring(char *s, char *t);
void readcontent(void);

void readcontent(void)
{

    char temp[100];
    char *tempptr;
    tempptr = temp;

    int c,i;
    i=c=0;

    while((c=getchar())!='\n'){
        if(c!=' ' && c!='\t' && c!='.'){
            *tempptr = c;
            tempptr++;
        }
        else{
            *tempptr = '\0';
            copystring((lineptr[i]=allocbuf()), temp);
            i++;
            tempptr=temp;
        }
    }
    if(c=='\n'){
        *tempptr = '\0';
        copystring((lineptr[i]=allocbuf()), temp);
        tempptr=temp;
        i++;
    }
}


void copystring(char *s, char *t)   /* copy t to s*/
{
    while(*t!='\0'){
        *s=*t;
        s++;
        t++;
    }
    s++;
    *s='\0';
}
```

Comment: Smells like undefined behavior.

Comment: (Haven't investigated the code itself yet) but if deleting an unused variable causes a crash you probably have undefined behavior lurking in your code.

Comment: You probably go out of bounds somewhere. [Learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and you should be able to find it.

Comment: By the way, your `copystring` have an off-by-one error. Why don't you use the standard `strcpy` function?

Comment: I bet Valgrind would tell you what's wrong.  You can return NULL from your alloc function, but you never check for it. `strdup` would likely be a better choice than what you're doing.

Comment: What is the expected output? What input causes a crash and what happens (exactly)?

There's a real chance that putting 'p=0' causes your program to "accidentally" null terminate an array.

Comment: Thank you folks! I will check ‘undefined behavior’. reason using a diy strcpy is just to get more familiar with the language (thank you for pointing out error).

Comment: The in put with error is “a a a a a a a a a a a a a”, without quotation mark, directly thirteen a with space in between. out put:                                      a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
(lldb)

Comment: Remove 2nd `s++;` from `copystring()`.

Comment: Sample `copystring()` replacement: `{
  while (*s++ = *t++);
}`